# Difference between using continue and stream filter operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there any advantage of using stream `filter` operation over iterator with `continue` operation?

Example `for` iteration:

```
for (ApiSite apiSite : sites) {
    Site mSite = Site.getSiteByName(apiSite.getName());
    if (mSite == null || deletedSitesToSkip.contains(mSite)) {
        LOGGER.info("Skipping site: {} as this has been deleted ", apiSite.getName());
        continue;
    }
    // operation
}
```

`stream` with `filter` example:

```
sites.stream().filter(apiSite -> {
    Site mSite = Site.getSiteByName(apiSite.getName());
    return (mSite != null && !deletedSitesToSkip.contains(mSite));
}).map(//some operation);
```

Comment: Declarative innit.

Comment: I think `stream API` is more readable

Comment: btw your examples don't match. In the first, you `getSiteByName`, which you don't in the second. You also reference `mSite` in the second which is undefined.

Comment: @Michael Fixed that the inconsistency - the question was more on usage of `filter` construct over loop with `continue`.

Answer (score 3):

First, the `filter` behavior depends on which terminal operation is invoked.

- **IF** a [short-circuiting terminal operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps), e.g:`anyMatch` is invoked, the `filter` will be exit until the first satisfied element.
- **IF** a non-short-circuiting terminal operation, e.g:`count`, `collect` is invoked, the `filter`'s behavior just like as yours. continue and process the next until the last.

Second, the stream api will make your code more **expressive**.

Third, Stream api allows you do some time-consuming operations in parallel . but `for` loop will take more effort to do it, for example:

```
stream.parallel().map(it-> remoteCall(it)).collect(...);
```

Fourth, Stream operation can be serialized, cached, the [apache spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/) core & streaming api is a framework that processing **distributed** operations on nodes in a cluster.

Comment: @Michael sir, I'm not good at english, you can edit my answer if mine has some typos.

Comment: Just the wrong form of the word. No big deal. :)

Comment: @Michael thanks very much, sir. I'm learning program also learning english too, :)

Answer (score 1):

The stream version has **better semantics**: you clearly operate on a set of data, filter it by a condition, and apply an operation on the matching elements. This adds to the **readability**, and allows to easily extend the processing by elementar building blocks (filter, map) without the risk of breaking much (**maintainability**).

Moreso, the streams operations (for filtering, mapping, ...) can be designed as reusable building blocks (DRY principle), which can be individualy tested, thus gaining **reliability**.

All in all, those are non-functional benefits (the functionality of both variants is the same), adding to the **quality of the code**.

Besides, `continue` is worth avoiding completely, as it quickly leads to awkward code when nesting loop blocks, making it hard to read and maintain.

Comment: I think in the second paragraph you mean reliability. Resilience is the ability to cope in the presence of errors.

Comment: I also strongly disagree that `continue` is worth avoiding completely.

Comment: Thanks, I now replaced 'resiliency' with 'reliability'.